# Enum value extraction

Tags: c#, enums

I have a enum type (i.e. `View`). I would like to extract a part of this enum [Top,Bottom,Left,Right,Front,Rear] to add in to a combo box as `ComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(View_extracted)).`

Is it possible?

```
enum View {Top,Bottom,Left,Right,Front,Rear,Trimetric,Isometric,Diametric}
```

`View_extracted` should contain first 6 values only:

```
{Top,Bottom,Left,Right,Front,Rear}
```

Comment: Since .NET 4.5 (2012), `ArraySegment<>` implements some collection interfaces, so maybe `new ArraySegment<View>((View[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(View)), 0, 6)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ to the rescue!

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(View)).Cast<View>().Take(6);
```

If you wanted it to be a proper enum, you can mess around with ILGen but it's way, **way** more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: That's not what the question asked though.  He asked to create a different enum that would define the values to take; this doesn't do that.

Comment: @Servy You could do a more complex search but then it'd just be as simple as putting it in as a compile-time list. Also, in the new update it says it's what he's looking for.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. No, he still says, even after the edit, that he's looking to have another enum that defines the items to take.

Comment: @Servy As in a complete new compile-time enum?

Comment: @It'sNotALie. That's what the question states.  Perhaps you should take the time to actually go read it before answering.

Comment: @Servy It wasn't clear beforehand, sorry. Doesn't help I'm not a native english speaker. Sorry.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. The edit did nothing but remove line breaks.  There is just as much info now as there was before.

Comment: @Servy I distinctly remember there not being the bottom View_extracted should contain bit.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Well, it was there.  I distinctly remember seeing it before.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's strictly not possible to create a type `View_extracted`, that would be able to be called using *that exact code* to create the stated results.

While you *could* create another enum that had values that happened to have the same names as this other enum, and you could create a method (that would have to be different than what you described) to get at a list of this enum's values, it's a very brittle system.

What I would suggest doing, instead of creating a new enum as a view, is to simply create a new method as a view that returns the values of this enum, something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<View> ExtractedView()
{
    //return a sequence of the views here, whether it be a hard code list,
    // or a filtered result of a call to Enum.GetValues, or whatever
}
```